# Fade out div then Fade in new div Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hash, fade

Ok, so I want to fade out my content upon click of a menu item and fade in the new content based on the a href link.
example: http://www.domain.com/index.php#home
I click Page 2
    #home fades out then #page2 fades in
http://www.domain.com/index.php#page2

I have uploaded the code to JSFiddle.

```
<>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/83GFu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/j45Lf/

Updated to use click handlers on document ready and then use a data attribute to know which page to show/hide.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navlist a").click(function(e){
      $(".page").hide();

      $("#" + $(this).data("page")).show();
    });        
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="navlist">
    <li class="litem" name="home">
        <a data-page="body_home" href="#body_home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="litem" name="hello">
        <a data-page="body_hello" href="#body_hello">Hello</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="body_home" class="page" style="display:none;>
  ...
</div>   

<div id="body_hello" class="page" style="display: none;">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: This works! Thank you! Is there anyway of making the links a hard link to the correct page (eg. index.php) if the user has Javascript Disabled?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't noticed it yet `$(document).ready()` is only fired upon page load or page refresh. Clicking `<a>` tag that only adds a fragment to the URL on the same page won't reload the page itself.

So you also need another handler for the `<a>` click with `click()` event.

```
$('.litem a').click(function () {

    ShowPage($(this).attr('href').substring(1))
});

function ShowPage(a) {
    $(".page").css("display", "none");//.hide() will do
    //don't need to set display, fadeIn already does that
    $("#body_" + a).fadeIn(1000)//.css("display", "block");
    //window.location.hash = "#" + a;, it's not necessary to reset the hash
    $(".litem").attr("id", "");
    $("li[name=" + a + "]").attr("id", "selected")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Is there anyway of making the links a hard link to the correct page (eg. index.php) if the user has Javascript Disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use .fadeIn() to have a more pretty then simply show.

Eg

> $(document).ready(function(){
>       $(".navlist a").click(function(e){
>           $(".page").hide();
>
> ```
>     $("#" + $(this).data("page")).fadeIn();
> });         });
> ```